# Azure AD - Report MFA registrations

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Is there a way to see a detailed report about the MFA registrations of the users in Azure AD?
I would like to see if the user has registered MFA with SMS, Phone call, Authenticator app (and which app), Authenticator push notification, etc.
I saw this report:
https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/AuthenticationMethodsMenuBlade/RegistrationAndResetLogs

But this report doesn't contain all details that I would like (for instance, if the user use SMS or phone call).

Answer (score 1):

You can surely get the detailed MFA registration authentication methods for the users through the Microsoft Graph query as follows:

Query: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.credentialUserRegistrationDetails)",
  "value":[
    {
      "id" : "id-value",
      "userPrincipalName":"userPrincipalName",
      "userDisplayName": "userDisplayName-value",
      "authMethods": ["email", "mobileSMS"],
      "isRegistered" : false,
      "isEnabled" : true,
      "isCapable" : false,
      "isMfaRegistered" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

Further, if you want the specific users who have enabled MFA registration authentication methods with **'email'**, **'SMS'**, **'Authenticator app'**, etc. Then use the optional query parameter with the above query as follows:

GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails?$filter=authMethods/any(t:t eq microsoft.graph.registrationAuthMethod'mobilePhone')`

The above query will give you the users who have enabled **'calling over Mobile phone'** as the MFA registration authentication methods. For more information, please find the documentation link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/credentialuserregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not able to fetch informations about SMS usage... how can I get them through Graph?

Comment: Just modify the above graph query and replace the 'mobilePhone' authmethod with 'mobileSMS' and then try, it should give you the details of the users with MFA authentication method as 'SMS'.